# Find-any-action shortcut netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

In (almost) every IDE there's a shortcut for full text search of actions/shortcuts. Meaning you initially only have to learn one shortcut in order to be effective.

- In Eclipse : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>
- In IntelliJ & co : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

Is there an equivalent in Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quick search toolbar at the top-right *Netbeans* corner, which allows to look for actions, etc.

[image]

Pressing <kbd>ctrl - I</kbd> will focus the field.